Angular Reactive Form Unique Identifier
How can I make the cnic to be a unique identifier? The form will not be submitted if this value is not unique and I want to be able to delete the object using this identifier.
Here is my code:
import { DialogRef } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatRadioButton, MatRadioGroup } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/service/employee.service';
import { LocalStateService } from 'src/app/service/localstateservice.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit',
  // imports;[MatRadioGroup,MatRadioButton],
  templateUrl: './add-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit.component.css'],
  
})
export class AddEditComponent {
  empform: FormGroup;
  education: string[] = [
    'Matric',
    'Diploma',
    'Intermiadiate',
    'Graduation',
    'Post Graduation'
  ];

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private _localStateService: LocalStateService, private _dialogueref: MatDialogRef<AddEditComponent>) {
    this.empform = this._fb.group({
      
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      email: '',
      education: '',
      dob: '',
      gender: '',
      company: '',
      cnic: '',
      address: '',
      experience: '',
      package: '',
      
    });
  }

  onClose(): void {
    this._dialogueref.close();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.empform.valid ) {
      this._localStateService.addEmployee(this.empform.value);
      this._dialogueref.close(true);
    }
  }

Here is my form:
<div class="form">
  <div mat-dialog-title>
    <h1 color="blue">Registration Form</h1>
  </div>

  <form [formGroup]="empform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          required="true"
          placeholder="Eg. Saad"
          formControlName="firstname"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Eg. Dastgir"
          formControlName="lastname"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          required="true"
          type="email"
          placeholder="test@takdev.org"
          formControlName="email"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Date Of Birth</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="picker"
          required="true"
          formControlName="dob"
        />
        <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
          matIconSuffix
          [for]="picker"
        ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <mat-radio-group
        aria-label="Select an option"
        required="true"
        formControlName="gender"
      >
        <mat-radio-button value="male">Male</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="female">female</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="others">Prefer not to say</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <!-- <h4> </h4> -->
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Qualification</mat-label>
        <mat-select required="true" formControlName="education">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let val of education" [value]="val"
            >{{val}}</mat-option
          >
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <h4></h4>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Company</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="takdev"
          type="text"
          formControlName="company"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Experience</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          required="true"
          placeholder="Eg. 02"
          type="number"
          formControlName="experience"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Package</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Eg. 100,000"
          type="number"
          formControlName="package"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>CNIC</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          color="primary"
          required="true"
          placeholder="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
          type="number"
          formControlName="cnic"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Street # City # Country #"
          type="text"
          formControlName="address"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <!-- <div mat-dialog-content></div> pending' add when datais loading-->
    <div mat-dialog-actions class="actions">
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onClose()">Cancel</button>
      <button mat-raised-button type="reset">Reset</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

I tried using Validators from @angular/forms but it does not work.

could you please explain in more detail on what is the issue?

I have a form in which it contains multiples section and from that section im generating a table, after generating the table i want to delete the data entered by the user using delete button that i have in the table, i want form to be not submit if cnic is same because if user two enter similar cnic in the form and add to the table after that if i click on either of user data and perform delete operation it will remove data of both users, therefore for that i want a condition in which form will not submit if cnic is not unique

Explain what cnic is for you, we don't know... Additionally, post the template HTML where your form is

cnic is a used to identify the single row of form data in the table and my logic include
deleteEmployee(cnic: number) {
this.employeeData = this.employeeData.filter(emp => emp.cnic !== cnic);
this.saveToLocalStorage();
}

Are you asking about Async custom validator?, you can take a look to this SO

Thank you so much i got the answer after looking into that
